# Yii - Multiple activeFileField throw HTTP 500

Tags: php, forms, yii

I am using 6 `CHtml::activeFileField` in my view:

```
<?php  echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'alt1', array('class'=>'imgInp', 'alt'=>1));?>

<?php  echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'alt2', array('class'=>'imgInp', 'alt'=>2)); ?>

<?php  echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'alt3', array('class'=>'imgInp', 'alt'=>3)); ?>

<?php  echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'alt4', array('class'=>'imgInp', 'alt'=>4)); ?>

<?php  echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'alt5', array('class'=>'imgInp', 'alt'=>5)); ?>

<?php  echo CHtml::activeFileField($model, 'alt6', array('class'=>'imgInp', 'alt'=>6)); ?>
```

When I run it in server, it throws error

> ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

But if I only use 3 `CHtml::activeFileField`, the view is rendered properly.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Didn't seem to find anything wrong with using 6 file fields in the form. It could have been a problem after submit but while rendering - that's surprising.

Comment: Does the model in question have attributes `"alt4", "alt5", "alt6"`? Also, do you have `YII_DEBUG` turned on so you can provide additional stack traces?

Comment: Yes, YII_DEBUG is turned on..

Comment: @IswantoSan Do you have anything in protected/runtime/errors.log?